# SQL - CASE with IN SELECT

Tags: sql, subquery, case, aggregate-functions, having

I am trying to isolate those records of `[table]` which **only** have specific (let's say *bad*) attributes. Bad attributes are those with ids 3, 6 and/or 7. To do that, I came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT x, y, id_attribute FROM [table]) 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN id_attribute IN (3, 6, 7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

and this works fine. I would now like to take this one step further and remove the hardcoding on the `(3, 6, 7)` since the bad attributes might change. So, instead, I want to replace `(3, 6, 7)` with `(SELECT DISTINCT id_attribute from [other_table] where description = 'bad')`.

But, when I put the two together, my query fails with the message:

*Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.*

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I think in the place of (3,6,7) you can write (SELECT LEFT(Id, LEN(Id) - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Id) + ', '
    FROM TableName
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) c (Id)
)

Comment: Why do you need `SELECT DISTINCT id_attribute FROM [other_table]`? Why would you have multiple entries? `SELECT id_attribute` should be enough?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I was trying to simplify my example. You are right, this is not needed but removing the distinct does not cut it.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: @AleixCC judging from the file extension (*.mdf), it must be Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Left Join` for isolating those bad attributes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT x, y, id_attribute,other_table.id as other_id_attribute FROM [table]
left join other_table on id_attribute=other_table.id
) 
GROUP by ....
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN other_id_attribute is not null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x, y, t.id_attribute 
FROM [table] t
WHERE t.id_attribute IN (
    SELECT ot.id_attribute 
    FROM [other_table] ot 
    WHERE ot.description = 'bad')
```